# Como tratar segurança em uma aplicação REST com Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth

Eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia tratar a segurança de uma aplicação stateless REST com o Spring.

Imagine que nenhum usuário possa acessar qualquer conteúdo de `/app/content` se não tiver identificado primeiramente. Existe como fazer isso sem precisar também fazer o tratamento em todos os métodos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Com Spring, o método de proteção recomendado é configurar o [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) para cuidar da **autenticação** e **autorização**.

## Autenticação

Para a [**autenticação**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication), há métodos prontos (JDBC, LDAP) ou você pode [criar sua própria implementação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#userdetailsservice-implementations).

Exemplo de autorização baseada em JDBC:

```java
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

## Autorização

Para a [**autorização**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#authorization), você pode proteger por URL ou método. Na verdade, há outras possibilidades (como usar o paradigma de Orientação a Aspectos), mas as duas apresentadas aqui são as fundamentais.

## Proteção por URL

Via código, é possível configurar o acesso por papel às diferentes URLs usando uma instância de `HttpSecurity`. Exemplo:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

Exemplo mais complexo:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_DBA')")  
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
            .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
}
```

Via XML, existe a tag `<intercept-url>`. Exemplo:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
        access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
    <form-login />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

## Proteção por método via anotação

É possível ativar autorizações via anotação nos *beans* do Spring com a seguinte configuração:

```xml
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

A anotação de segurança mais útil e comumente usada é a `@PreAuthorize`, que verifica se o usuário realmente poderia estar executando aquele método.

Exemplo:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

Aqui a anotação foi incluída numa `interface`, mas poderia estar também na classe concreta. Isso depende um pouco da arquitetura usada na sua aplicação.

## Considerações

Os tópicos mencionados são apenas um resumo muito resumido do Spring Security. Existem vários outros pontos de extensão e customização que podem ser aproveitados dependendo do contexto.

Apenas espero que esta tenha sido uma introdução proveitosa.