# Como fazer segurança de REST com Spring Security

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, restful, spring-security

Pessoal estou tentando implementar segurança no meu servidor REST feito com SPRING 4. Estou trabalhando com anotações.

O basico do spring security para proteger páginas eu conheço. 
Mas como proteger a requisições para o RESTful ?

Comment: Veja se esse artigo lhe ajuda: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/

Comment: Olá Clebio! Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Como dito pelo @GiancarloAbelGiulian, sua pergunta provavelmente já possui uma resposta. Por favor, [verifique se esta resposta lhe atende](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35312/4816) e, caso não atenda, edite a sua pergunta para que inclua as informações que você acredita não terem sido respondidas na pergunta anterior.